# add a direction to send characters in encryption python code

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
text='hijklqrs'       
def encrypt(shift_text,shift_amount, direction):
    cipher_text=[]
    for i in shift_text:                      
        if direction is right:                   
            cipher_text.append(text[(text.index(i) + shift_amount) % 26])    
        else:
            cipher_text.append(text[(text.index(i) - shift_amount) % 26])           
    output = ''.join(cipher_text)
    return output
```

So far this is the code I have created, however the issue I am having is that I need to be able to shift my text to the left or right dependent upon the direction parameter in my function. I am unsure how to add to the code that I want the shift to move to the left. So for example when I take `h` into the function and the shift amount is 2 and the direction is left it will return `f`.

Comment: Could you please verify your code indentation for the `encrypt` function?

Comment: The code is indented I have changed my if statement to reflect what I think is needed for the shift direction to be correct. The parameter direction if sent to the right would add the shift amount, otherwise it is subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotate(alphabet,shift):
    return alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]

print rotate("abcdefghijk",2)
```

you then pair it up using a dictionary or string.transtab and translate your original text with your shifted text

```
from string import maketrans,ascii_lowercase
N = -13 #shift ammount (use negative for "left" and positive for "right")
tab = maketrans(ascii_lowercase,rotate(ascii_lowercase,N))
encoded = "hello world".translate(tab)
decode_tab = maketrans(rotate(ascii_lowercase,N),ascii_lowercase)
decoded = encoded.translate(decode_tab)
print encoded,"--->",decoded
```